# How to put the "text" into a database?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I generated the following using a Keyword extraction API
(I searched for "Hitler" because no one is trying to sell you things when you search for him.)

```
x=[{"relevance"=>"0.592174", "text"=>"eight-year-old Hitler"}, {"relevance"=>"0.589796", "text"=>"Hitler states"}, {"relevance"=>"0.589118", "text"=>"Hitler lived."}, {"relevance"=>"0.585102", "text"=>"Hitler learnt"}, {"relevance"=>"0.580278", "text"=>"Hitler Youth"}, {"relevance"=>"0.414842", "text"=>"German Workers"}, {"relevance"=>"0.413532", "text"=>"German military leaders"}, {"relevance"=>"0.404701", "text"=>"nazi party"}, {"relevance"=>"0.391943", "text"=>"Mein Kampf"}, {"relevance"=>"0.388932", "text"=>"Reichstag"}, ]
```

So the database should have :

```
Eight-year-old hitler
Hitler states
...
```

I've tried `x.each do |x|` and

```
x.to_a.each do
x["text"]
x
```

None of which work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you haven't given the following information, I will make some assumptions:

- Database table name
- Schema for table
- Model name
- ORM

Let's rename `x` to `search_results`. Let's also assume that we have a table in  the database called `search_results`, a model called `SearchResult`, that the `search_results` table has a column called `text`, and that we are using ActiveRecord as the ORM:

```
search_results.each do |data| 
  SearchResult.create(text: data[:text])
end
```

Or since you have an array of hashes, simply:

```
SearchResult.create(search_results)
```